# Android studio is not creating object using another class

Tags: java, android, android-studio

`WeatherDataModel weatherDataModel = new WeatherDataModel.fromJson(response);`

I am creating a `WeatherDataModel`*(my second class)* object using the method `fromJson` ( defined in `WeatherDataModel` class) in my `MainActivity` using the parameters response.

But when I write above code Android studio can't recognize `fromJson`, but when I write this:

```
WeatherDataModel weatherDataModel = new WeatherDataModel();
weatherDataModel.fromJson(response);
```

It doesn't show any error.

**Is there's a difference between these 2 lines?**

Comment: "IS there's a difference " - yes, there is one: you forgot the `()` after WeatherDataModel in the first line

Comment: You forgot to actually invoke the constructor with `()`

Comment: (3) You forgot to call constructor ()

Comment: Probably you want a _static factory method_, which is neither a constructor nor an instance method. You would define it as `public static WeatherDataModel fromJson(String json)` and call it as `WeatherDataModel w = WeatherDataModel.fromJson(response)`. What you have today is a broken hybrid of a constructor and a static factory.

Comment: You need to call your construction with () that's the difference, otherwise both are same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an instance of an object before call a method,
so you code should be like this.

```
WeatherDataModel weatherDataModel = new WeatherDataModel().fromJson(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you missed the brackets for the constructor or you can even get rid of the `new` keyword by declaring the `fromJson` method static, which would make even more sense from a point of readability of the code.

If `fromJson` is not static, it can be called on a living instance at any time, destroying any values already stored in that instance.

So I'd declare that method as

```
public static WeatherDataModel fromJson(String response) {
    WeatherDataModel wd = new WeatherDataModel();
    // parse your response into wd's fields
    return wd;
}
```

and from outside your call then looks like

```
WeatherDataModel model = WeatherDataModel.fromJson(response);
```

Hope this helps, cheers

Comment: Thank you everyone

Comment: I am actually new to Android, just started a week ago.

Comment: Thank you so much     My app works perfectly fine now